# How to describe function with parameters and template literal?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm creating typings for a third party module that my project is using.

One of the functions is called as such:

```
callFunc(paramOne, paramTwo)`
  stringLiteral: ${something},
  somethingElse: ${here}
`;
```

I'm trying to figure out how to describe such a function in typescript but the typescript documentation didn't really help in this specific case. The first two parameters I know how to describe but how do I add a typing for the template / string literal?

Comment: Is this [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates)? Does `callFunc` return a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are functions where the first argument is of type `TemplateStringsArray` and then the rest of the arguments are just the values of expressions in the template. So for example we can define `t`:

```
function t(s: TemplateStringsArray, ...a:any[]) {
  console.log(t); // will output ["a", "b"]  for the example below
  console.log(a); // will output [0] for the example below
  return ""
}

t`a${0}b`
```

In your case the function `callFunc(paramOne, paramTwo)` returns a tagged template, so the definition should look something like:

```
declare function callFunc(paramOne: string, paramTwo: number) : (s: TemplateStringsArray, ...a:any[]) => string;


callFunc("", 1)`a${0}`
```

Made a few assumptions about parameter types, but except for `TemplateStringsArray` everything else is dependent on the specifics of your library